# Match a specific Unicode number regardless of script

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, unicode

I am using Python 3 and I am trying to achieve something like the following.

Given the following Unicode regex which is the default in Python 3:

```
regex = r'^\d{5}$'
```

This will match 5 Unicode numbers from 0 to 9.

Is there a way to specify a number say `9` where `9` will be matched no matter what language was used for input?

I am in a situation where users may have mixed input and specifying every possible Unicode number like `\u0031` isn't ideal.

Comment: Language or script? If you mean script, you will need to use a custom character class to match any `9`s.

Comment: would you kindly elaborate in using a custom character class?

Comment: See [the online demo](https://ideone.com/pCHnrD) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CcC17W/1).

Comment: thank you ! do you mind sharing how you generated those character classes?this is what I want as long as I don't have to type it one by one.

Comment: I used [this tool](https://r12a.github.io/uniview/). You need a way to parse the whole Unicode table and look for the characters whose names contain a whole word `NINE`, `EIGHT`, etc, and create a character class from those Unocode chars. For those that are outside the BMP plane, you need to transpile them, and [this tool](http://r12a.github.io/apps/conversion/) turns out handy. Well, you might also use `\Uxxxxxxxx` notation for those.